# gdb breakpoint in a 32 bit compiled application, executed on a 64 bit machine is not getting hit

Tags: gdb, nasm

I'm running a basic assembly program that was compiled on a 32 bit machine on a 64 bit machine. I know there is a breakpoint called _start. When I issue the `break _start` command I receive:

```
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048080
```

When I run the application the application doesn't break at the set breakpoint, but just keeps going.

A small excerpt from the code:

```
global _start           

section .text
_start:

    jmp Begin
```

What could be the reason that my breakpoint is not getting hit?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a nop as the first instruction.  Then you can do

```
breakpoint *_start+1
```

This is due to a bug in gdb.  You can do

```
disassemble _start
```

to see all of the breakpoints you can set with the *_start+offset format.